# Loading a CSV file from Google Sheets

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher

`LOAD CSV` returns error:

> there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote
>   there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote.
>   That isn't supported. This is what I read: '> <div class="c'

I followed the directions from https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/import-csv-locations

I have confirmed that the csv file is comma delimited with no quotes. See below:

```
user_id,latitude,longitude
6000,39.5990448,-104.7583542
6001,39.74534607,-104.9971695
```

Here's the cypher command:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a1AHwH57AylKSHKE3NwHZ-O3WNcWW6RZ-BVkaRPtEFk/export?format=csv" AS line
CREATE (:Calendar {
  user_id:line.user_id,
  location:point({latitude:toFloat(line.latitude), longitude:toFloat(line.longitude)})
})
```

I can't figure out where Cypher is seeing a quote.  It seems to reading an HTML format but I have confirmed that the link simply requests to save the csv file.

I've reviewed the other submitted questions and they all point to errant quotes in the csv file but the one I'm testing with is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  A gracious stackoverflow user clicked the link and had to request permission.  I had given the uploaded .csv file permission but when I converted to gsheet to download as a csv to get the download link I had not given permission to THAT gsheet file.  Once I gave view permission it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the result that i got. I don't see any error while uploading